# How to create and open SQLite table in Android?

Tags: android, sql

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("tompomodoros.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE mytable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, mydate VARCHAR, mydata SMALLINT)");
```

I use above code to create db and its table "mytable". But for the second time I run it, the phone goes to dead. I guess that is because I create the table again but it already exists there.
So my question is how to create the table for the first time and open it for the rest times?

Comment: The simplest way it to use the `SQLiteOpenHelper` which does all the version checking for you http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#sqliteoverview_sqliteopenhelper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [`if not exists`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html):

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists mytable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, mydate VARCHAR, mydata SMALLINT)");
```

and then us it as usual.

Answer (score 1):

First check if the table exists, use the following:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT tbl_name FROM sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name = 'mytable'", null);
if(cursor == null || cursor.getCount() == 0) { //table does not exist
        //create the Db attachments table
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE mytable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, mydate VARCHAR, mydata SMALLINT)");
}
cursor.close();
```